# Should I wrap all codes into runOnUiThread even some code doesn't need to run on UI thread?

Tags: coding-style, android

In android, some codes, such as updating UI buttons, needs to be called in UI thread, however, before UI update, some task, such as getting response from internet, need to be done on another thread, here is the most common form of response callback I see:

```
public void httpResponseCallback(String responseString){
    MyFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            if(responseString==null || responseString.isEmpty()){
                showErrorDialog();
            }else{
                List<String> nameList=this.parse(responseString);
                if(nameList==null){
                    showErrorDialog();
                }else{
                    updateUI(nameList);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I think this callback is not good enough, because some codes doesn't require to place inside runOnUiThread, so I think the following form is better:

```
public void httpResponseCallback(String responseString){
    if(responseString==null || responseString.isEmpty()){

        MyFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                showErrorDialog();
        }
        });
    }else{
        final List<String> nameList=this.parse(responseString);
        if(nameList==null){

            MyFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                showErrorDialog();
            }
        });
        }else{

            MyFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                updateUI(nameList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After refactoring, at start, I think it would be more logical because:

1. It reduce unnecessary workload on UI thread
2. It give hints to other teammates that which functions or codes need to run on UI thread

But later when I read the code again, I found the code is far longer than the original one because of extra runOnUiThread to type, so my question is, is wrapping all codes into runOnUiThread better than using runOnUiThread only on UI related code?

Comment: Where do you stop? What if `showErrorDialog` or `updateUI` also contain code that doesn't *need* to execute in the UI thread?

Comment: If you use lambdas it's likely to look a lot less horrible

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience you shouldn't put the codes that are irrelevant to `UI` inside the `runOnUiThread {}` block. for example when you need to check the `MediaPlayer` status (`playing` or `stopped`) inside a thread, if you put the `MediaPlayer.isPaying()` statement within a `runOnUiThread{}` block you will be encountered with a ***not responsible*** behavior in your android application.

Comment: It's unlikely MediaPlayer.isPlaying will block the ui thread.

Comment: @Ccm i tested it and it is responsible

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, ever wait for anything on a UI thread. You call an asynchronous method to read data from the internet, which might take some time, pass a callback method, and that method runs the rest of your code on the ui thread.

Comment: Where in the snippet do they call an api? (Its implied to happen before the call, but that's not on the UI thread either way)